# Best fit line using geometric distance (not vertical distance)

Tags: statistics, regression

There must be a theory of finding the best fit line to a bunch of points in the plane, where "best fit" is defined by the geometric distance, not vertical distance.  In other words, we are trying to minimize the sum of the squares of the distances from the points to the line, where the distance is measured along lines that are perpendicular to the best fit.  What is this theory called, and where can I learn about it?

Comment: See [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) and [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and their references.

Comment: If you mean "straight line" I think, the concept of "principal components" should be the one you're looking for. It includes, for instance, a rotation of the bunch-of-points such that the best-fit-line can be the x-axis -and the problem is again reduced to least vertical distances. However, I'm not sure of it at the moment. Wikipedia has a chapter on principal components. If you don't think of straight lines but of curves, there is the keyword "nonlinear regression" under which you might find more.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Deming regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression), which is a special (bivariate) case of [total least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) aka orthogonal regression.