# Best fitting "curve"

Tags: statistics, polynomials, regression, curves

> Let $P$ be an $n$th degree  polynomial.  Find the $(n-1)$st degree polynomial $R$, whose arithmetic mean of distances to all of the points $P$ passes be minimum.

[Best fit line using geometric distance (not vertical distance)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564396/best-fit-line-using-geometric-distance-not-vertical-distance) is similar, but it doesn't help. Maybe it can be solved by using Deming Regression and limits ($\Delta x\to0$), but I don't know how to do it.

Calculus does what Deming Regression does, in a harder way. Maybe it's possible to use calculus "optimization" to do that, if it's not too complex.

Comment: I am confused with the term *sum of distances to all of the points $P$ passes*. In what space is this? In the real numbers this will always be infinitely large, since there are infinitely many points with distance $>0$?

Comment: @RoyPJ see edit.